# Multi-level query to get value from second sub-query to drive parent element

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get a multi-level query to give me what seems to me to be a simple answer. I have 2500 rows of data against postcodes. Each row holds a postcode, person's initials, primary cost and secondary cost. I want to get the lowest cost for a postcode based upon the primary cost - that bit's easy - but then if there is more than one person with the same primary cost for the same postcode I need return the one with the lowest secondary cost.
Example:

```
postcode, initials, p_cost, s_cost
AB12    , DS      , 100   , 0
AB12    , JH      , 100   , 40
AB12    , SS      , 120   , 0
```

So from this, I would like to pull out DS as they have the lowest primary cost along with JH, but they also have the lowest secondary cost of the two.
Here's the SQL I have so far:

```
SELECT initials, min(s_cost) FROM
    (SELECT * FROM MyTable
     WHERE postcode = 'AB12'
     and p_cost = 
        (select min(p_cost) from MyTable 
         WHERE postcode = 'AB12'));
```

I also tried:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE postcode = 'AB12' 
and p_cost = (select min(p_cost) 
               from MyTable 
               WHERE postcode = 'AB12'
               and s_cost = (select min(s_cost) 
                                     from MyTable 
                                     WHERE postcode = 'AB12'));
```

Can someone please put me out of my misery here, it should be simple but it's 15 years since I last wrote and SQL in anger and this is really bugging me.

Thanks for your help everyone :-)

Comment: Im not clear what is the result you want? DS, JH or both? Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: As I said in the question I want to pull out DS i.e. the row with the lowest primary and secondary cost. The table schema is shown with the sample data provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need calculate what is the lowest p_cost for each postcode

```
 SELECT postcode, MIN(primary_cost) as min_primary_cost
 FROM MyTable 
 WHERE postcode = 'AB12'
```

Now you need to calculate what is the min for secondary_cost but based on primary cost

```
 SELECT primary_cost, MIN(secondary_cost) as min_primary_cost
 FROM MyTable 
 WHERE postcode = 'AB12'
 GROUP BY primary_cost
```

Now join both together

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/EJMS5294)**

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
JOIN ( SELECT postcode, MIN(primary_cost) as min_primary_cost
       FROM YourTable 
       WHERE postcode = 'AB12'
     ) as p_cost
ON YourTable.postcode = p_cost.postcode
AND YourTable.primary_cost = p_cost.min_primary_cost
JOIN ( SELECT primary_cost, MIN(secondary_cost) as min_secondary_cost
       FROM YourTable 
       WHERE postcode = 'AB12'
       GROUP BY primary_cost
     ) as s_cost
  ON YourTable.primary_cost = s_cost.primary_cost
 AND YourTable.secondary_cost= s_cost.min_secondary_cost
WHERE postcode = 'AB12'
```

Comment: This gave me just what I needed once I changed the and to as in the field alias. Thanks very much :-)

Comment: First was a typo and then carry over by the copy/paste, but is fix on the demo

Comment: btw you need on aditional `WHERE postcode = 'AB12'` at the end

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried joining your table to itself with the join criteria being the filter?

```
select mt1.* 
from mytable mt1
left join mytable mt2 
    on mt1.postcode = mt2.postcode 
        and ( mt1.p_cost < mt2.p_cost 
         or (mt1.p_cost = mt2.p_cost and mt1.s_cost < mt2.s_cost)
        )
where mt1.postcode = 'AB12'
```

This code is untested by the way.

Comment: You need extra parenthesis for the `OR` still not sure if that bring you the right result

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try this.

```
Select * 
from MyTable 
where postcode = 'AB12' 
order by p_cost asc, s_cost asc 
limit 1;
```

Comment: You are right, if already filtering postcode limit 1 will do the job.